# ReactJs, update state after redirect

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with updating the state of a component after a redirect. Actually I have two components getItems.js and addItem.js

**App.js**

```
const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const fetch =  () => {
     axios.get('localhost:3000/api/get_all.php')
        .then(response => {
             setItems(response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }

    fetch();
}, [])

return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="container">
      <Routes
        <Route path="/" element={<getItems items={items}/>} />
        <Route path='/add-item' element={<addItem />} />
      </Routes>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

)

**getItems.js**

> This component is used to display each item from App.js

**addItem.js**

```
 const onSubmit = (event) => {
    const item = {
     ...
    }

    axios.post('localhost:3000/api/add_item.php', item)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

On App.js I have a button to direct to add-item page, once I save the item and redirect to App.js page the items state is not updated, only if I reload the entire page.

Comment: After an actual redirect? (This isn't reflected in the code shown.) A *redirect* will reload the page; unless the state is persisted or rehydrated you'll lose *all* your state. If the issue is that the added item isn't showing up it's because you're not adding it to the state/props of the component that is responsible for displaying it.

Comment: I'm just using a button with <Link></Link> to redirect to App.js

Comment: A "redirect" is a specific thing. A link to a replacement page is a specific thing. An SPA that shows components based on routing is neither of those, and the browser + router behavior depends on the actual `<Link>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the state after adding an item. Since your logic is separated in two routes, you will have to use a contextProvider

Basically, it allows you to share state anywhere in your app.

ContextProvider.js

```
//Set initial value. We wont use it but we need t odefined it here
export const ContextProvider = createContext({
items: undefined
setItems: () => {}
});
```

App.js

```
export const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

//Pass state to context
  const contextValue = {
    items: items,
    setItems: setItems,
  };

useEffect(() => {
    const fetch =  () => {
     axios.get('localhost:3000/api/get_all.php')
        .then(response => {
             setItems(response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }

    fetch();
}, [])

return (
    <ContextProvider.Provider value={contextValue}>
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="container">
      <Routes
        <Route path="/" element={<getItems/>} />
        <Route path='/add-item' element={<addItem />} />
      </Routes>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
    </ContextProvider.Provider>
)
};
```

GetItems.js

```
//instead of prop.items
const {items} = useContext(Contextprovider)
```

addItem.js

```
const {items, setitems} = useContext(Contextprovider)

    axios.post('localhost:3000/api/add_item.php', item)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            //Validate if item is added
            if(response.data) {
        //Push new item to list
        setItem([...item, response.data])
}
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

Comment: but, I can't update the state in addItem.js component,it's defined in App.js

Comment: You need to better structure your routes. Either have the whole logic in one route, or use a context provider. I'll update the answer with another example

Comment: I had another issue this time after I submit I get the data I inserted but with an additionl empty Array, it keeps each time I submit.

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(response.data)?

Comment: Just one successful item created. by the way I changed in your code setItem([...item, response.data]) to setItem([...items, item])

Comment: But once I reload the page I found an empty array along with the inserted one.

Comment: Where did you find it and what exactly does it look like? Like one array with 2 arrays inside or is it at first an empty array, and then an filled array?

Comment: a filled array than an empty one where  properties are all null when I reload the page. when I checked the server I found that the empty array is first created.

Comment: items will always be empty at first, since you have to wait for your server to bring that data back.

Comment: But why an empty one is create at first ? By the way this is how I initialized the array const item = { name: state.name, summary: state.summary }... and an initial state const [state, setState] = useState({ name: '', summary: ''  })